# Laravel5.8でtransactionでなぜかロールバックされてしまう

Tags: php, laravel-5

いつもお世話になっております。
Laravel5.8/php7.3 にて開発をしております。
複数テーブルのinsertの処理があったので`\DB::transaction`を使ってトランザクションの処理を行っております。

ローカル環境では、なんの問題もなく複数テーブルの登録が出来たのですが、本番環境にアップするとなぜか登録がされない状況です。

```
function __invoke() {
    $uesr = $this->store();
    var_dump($user); // <- 登録した内容が取得出来ているし、新規登録されたIDも発番されている
}
function store() {
    return \DB::transaction(function () use () {
        $data = ['email'=>'test@mail.com', name'=>'test'];
        $user = new User;
        $user->fill($data)->save();

        $post = Post::create(['user_id'=>$user->id]);
        return $user;
    });
}
```

上記のように、transactionの処理が完了し、var_dumpでは新規に発番されたIDの取得は出来ております。
ただ、データベースには登録されておらず、ロールバックされてしまっているような動きをしております。

- トランザクションの処理をやめれば、正常に登録される
- トランザクション内でエラー(Exception)発生時にはvar_dumpまでは表示されないこと

などは、確認しているのですが、他に確認する点、修正すべき点等がございましたら、ご教授頂けますと幸いでございます。

何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

$user_idは$user->idではないでしょうか？

蛇足ですが、transactionはtry/catchで囲むとロールバックした際に例外をキャッチできるので、原因をつかみやすいです。
あと、userとpostがリレーションしている場合は、「関連したモデルの挿入」を使ったほうが、idを意識しなくてすみます。

```
try {
    $user = \DB::transaction(function () {
        // 保存
        $user = User::create(['email'=>'test@mail.com', 'name'=>'test']);
        $post = $user->posts()->create(['comment' => 'コメント']);
        return $user;
    )};
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    report($e);
    // ロールバック時の処理
}
```

※ コードはタイポなどあるかもしれません。

Comment: そもそもtry/catchに入れないとロールバックしなかったかもしれません。

Comment: > $user_idは$user->idではないでしょうか？　　こちら、ご指摘の通りでした。質問内容を修正いたしました。